# Using one USB-C port for PD and Video on a monitor

Tags: display, usb-c, charging, hub

I have a question regarding my mobile monitor setup. I utilize the Asus Zenscreen MB16AMT as my third monitor, and I also use it when I'm away from the office.

I'd like to know if it's possible to use the USB-C input port on the monitor for screen sharing from my computer while simultaneously utilizing PD (Power Delivery) to charge the monitor.

I am aware that this monitor can be charged via USB-C when connected to the computer, but it doesn't seem like the most optimal choice for me. This method only extends the monitor's battery life for a few more hours.

I'm interested in using a splitter or a merger (depending on your recommendation) on the monitor to facilitate both charging and screen sharing simultaneously.

PS: I've tried several USB-C hubs on the monitor but was unable to achieve screen sharing, only receiving PD. I suspect most of the hubs operate in a one-way direction.

Comment: USB Type-C splitters don't exist.  USB works due to a host client negation. The same is very true even with the power delivery capabilities; if a USB Type-C hub doesn't achieve your goal, then your monitor cannot support your goal.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, whether your setup ends up with a net-positive or -neutral device charge depends on the power rating of the auxiliar power source, i.e., the PD power-in rating on your hub, as balanced against your total demand/load?  You should determine the total consumption of each of your peripherals/devices (both running as well as starting) and then purchase a hub that supports up to the sum of the anticipated starting loads to be safe.  Note that you may need to contact the OEM's directly to obtain accurate specs if not specified in default documentation and each device may differ.

Answer (score 0):

The spec seems to allow simultaneous PD+DP Alt Mode (video), however most commercially available video sources are unlikely to output PD, as this requires significant additional circuitry and TDP. Currently, the most direct and easiest way to achieve your desired result would be to use a USB PD capable charger along with a mini HDMI cable for the video signal, though this will require two cables.

A USB PD "injection" device may become available; at the time of this writing, USB PD devices are available as relatively expensive developer boards (which need an external housing) and do no explicitly state they support DP Alt mode (e.g. https://www.coolgear.com/product/dev-product-60w-pd-device-injector-pcba-w-data-amplification). Eventually you may find a more consumer friendly device that provides this functionality sold as an "OTG" cable.

You may (or may not) have luck with an older GPU that has VirtualLink, or VirtualLink adapters (e.g. https://www.bizlinktech.com/products/detail/1332/VirtualLink%E2%84%A2+Interface+Adapter), intended for VR headsets, although that spec isn't explicitly the same as DP Alt mode or PD, it can provide up to 27W of power along with video. As this spec was essentially abandoned it may be hard to find a device and it may not be fruitful.